# Create new div and increase size on mouse idle with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jquery to create a new div on my mouse's position when my mouse goes idle for x amount of time. If it stays idle the div will increase in size. When I move my mouse the new div that was created will still be in place. How would I go about doing this with the jquery attached below? I think it should follow the same logic? Many thanks.

```js
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false;
idleWait = 2000;

(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        $('*').bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function () {
        
            clearTimeout(idleTimer);
                    
            if (idleState == true) { 
                
                // Reactivated event
                $("body").append("<p>Welcome Back.</p>");            
            }
            
            idleState = false;
            
            idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 
                
                // Idle Event
                $("body").append("<p>You've been idle for " + idleWait/1000 + " seconds.</p>");

                idleState = true; }, idleWait);
        });
        
        $("body").trigger("mousemove");
    
    });
}) (jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Bind()` is deprecated, you should use `on()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an interval to check the idle state. My example might not be 100% what you want but you should be able to adjust it to your likings.

```js
var idleTimer = null;
var idleState = false;
var idleWait = 2000;
var idleInterval = 1000;
var idleStartTime = Date.now();
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Set a interval that checks the idle state
    setInterval(function() {
      if (idleState == true) {
        //add element if it doensn't excist, otherwise update it
        if ($('#idleDiv').length === 0) {
          var $el = $('<div>');
          $el.attr('id', 'idleDiv');
          $el.css('left', mouseX);
          $el.css('top', mouseY);

          $el.html('<p>You\'ve been idle for ' + ((Date.now() - idleStartTime) / 1000) + ' seconds.</p>');
          $("body").append($el);
        } else {
          $('#idleDiv').html('<p>You\'ve been idle for ' + ((Date.now() - idleStartTime) / 1000) + ' seconds.</p>');
        }
        //change the height when idle
        $('#idleDiv').height($('#idleDiv').height() + 10);
      }
    }, idleInterval);

    //sets the idleState to false on mousemove events and to true when no mouse move happended for 'idleWait' milliseconds.
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(event) {
      idleStartTime = Date.now();
      idleState = false;

      clearTimeout(idleTimer);

      idleTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        idleState = true
      }, idleWait);

      //Set the mouse coordinates
      mouseX = event.pageX;
      mouseY = event.pageY;
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#idleDiv {
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great. I'll check it out more and learn how to adjust. Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest following steps:

1. In the bind function(), pass the event as a parameter.
2. Inside the idletimeout function, create a div element, with absolute positioning, left and top based on mouse coordinates

var elem = "";
$(div).append(elem);
lastElem = $(div).last();

3. Set an interval to run after each specified time so that it will increase the size of lastElem accordingly. Clear the interval when mouse moves.

I have outlined the points here, you can get the actual code by researching a bit...it is all available on the internet.

Hope it helps.